# Is spacetime flat inside a spherical shell?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, metric-tensor, curvature

In a perfectly symmetrical spherical hollow shell, there is a null net gravitational force according to Newton, since in his theory the force is exactly inversely proportional to the square of the distance.

What is the result of general theory of relativity? Is the spacetime flat inside (given the fact that orbit of Mercury rotates I don't think so)? How is signal from the cavity redshifted to an observer at infinity?

Comment: "Is the spacetime flat" seems like a strange and possibly misleading way to put it...  if something analogous to Newton's Shell Theorem is applicable here,  that tells you only that the net curvature caused *by the shell* is zero... even if that's the case, that still wouldn't imply spacetime is flat inside, since there may be *other* objects in the universe, outside the shell, that are exerting forces and warping that region of space, right?

Comment: The GR case isn't quite as analogous to the Newtonian case as you might think, or as important. GR is nonlinear, so you can't treat a spherically symmetric mass distribution as the sum of concentric shells. And there is an ambiguity in how we pose the problem. For example, the spacetime of a freely collapsing shell of dust is given by an Oppenheimer-Snyder solution, whereas the spacetime for a shell held in static equilibrium by internal forces is different. Things like redshifts at infinity aren't well defined if it's not static.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Here we will only answer OP's two first question(v1).  Yes, [Newton's Shell Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) generalizes to [General Relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity) as follows. The [Birkhoff's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_theorem_%28relativity%29) states that a spherically symmetric solution is static, and a (not necessarily thin) vacuum shell (i.e. a region with no mass/matter) corresponds to a radial branch of the [Schwarzschild solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric)

$$\tag{1} ds^2~=~-\left(1-\frac{R}{r}\right)c^2dt^2 
+ \left(1-\frac{R}{r}\right)^{-1}dr^2 +r^2 d\Omega^2$$

in some radial interval $r \in I:=[r_1, r_2]$. Here the constant $R$ is the [Schwarzschild radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius), and $d\Omega^2$ denotes the metric of the angular $2$-sphere.

Since there is no mass $M$ at the center of OP's internal hollow region $r \in I:=[0, r_2]$, the Schwarzschild radius $R=\frac{2GM}{c^2}=0$ is zero. Hence the metric (1) in the hollow region is just flat Minkowski space in spherical coordinates.

Comment: Nice job. Sigh. It really annoys me that someone can write a nice reply to a nice question and end up with a "0" score even after it's selected as the answer to the question. Do people think they have to pay for +s out of their bank account?

Comment: A simple and beautiful answer indeed!

Comment: Does this conclusion still hold if we have a non-vanishing positive cosmological constant?

Comment: Yes, but the role of Minkowski space is then replaced by de Sitter space.

Comment: But Leos also asked about the redshift of the light from the cavity.

Comment: It's the same as the redshift from the surface

Comment: @Qmechanic Substituting $R=0$ In $(1)$ does not produce the correct time dilation inside the shell. In other words, this metric does not satisfy the junction conditions across the shell. What is the correct formula for the metric inside?

Comment: @Qmechanic Here is the correct solution: https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.4428

Comment: @safesphere: Thanks for the feedback. Indeed the relations between coordinate systems _inside,_ _outside_ and _on_ the infalling thin shell is non-trivial.

Comment: The OP asked "How is signal from the cavity redshifted to an observer at infinity?," but the answer doesn't address this. The Zhang and Yi paper does discuss this.

Comment: @safesphere: *Substituting R=0 In (1) does not produce the correct time dilation inside the shell. In other words, this metric does not satisfy the junction conditions across the shell. What is the correct formula for the metric inside?* There is nothing incorrect about writing the metric in this form. The Zhang paper just points out that the coordinates used in writing the metric this way cannot be connected in a natural and continuous way to the Schwarzschild coordinates in the exterior region.

Comment: @BenCrowell The paper clarifies that "*discontinuous time term of the metric at all interior boundaries, i.e., the clocks are defined differently at both sides of a boundary [...] is clearly nonphysical, and also mathematically incorrect*".

Comment: @safesphere have just found it. I understand now better what you have meant. The paper I have referenced seem to be mathematically not correct as well (singularity at the center). I work on it.

Comment: @safesphere I have studied already that paper and have seen one problem. They set two boundary conditions on pressure (eq. 10), where there is only one allowed, and use them to determine $\rho_{0}$ (eq. 50). In my view it is not correct.

Comment: @safesphere is spacetime of a hollow shell in static equilibrium?

Comment: @safesphere it is about the same what I am thinking. Regarding shell I work on math about it now. Fluid free fall is possible only for pressureless "dust" particles. This is a problem because the true cause for black hole phenomenon in classical GR is unbounded pressure.