# The metric Tensor inside a massive shell

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity

Given a fixed shell with the mass of $M$ and a radius $R$ , 
what would be the metric tensor for $r<R$? 
I do know that using Birkhoff Theorem the metric for $r>R$ should be schwarzschild. 
I'm not sure how to solve $G_{\mu\nu}=0$ for the inner part, and I'm not sure if I can demand continuity at $r=R$.

Comment: The region inside the shell should have a Minkowski (flat) metric, certainly not a zero metric.

Comment: By $G_{\mu\nu}$ I meant to Einstein tensor, the equation above is the field equation under energy-momentum tensor $T_{\mu\nu}=0$ .

Comment: This is worked quite beautifully in Poisson's book.  The interesting case is when the shell is spinning.

Comment: @FranzUnberlaude : Aaaah! Sorry. I think that the metrics inside has to be Minkowski.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43626/2451

Comment: Why the reopen vote? This seems an obvious duplicate so why vote to reopen it?

Comment: Oops, I accidentally voted to leave close. I have now VTrOed.

Answer (score 1):

As  Qmechanic said, this question been answered [before](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43626/is-spacetime-flat-inside-a-spherical-shell)
. to sum it up, as the birkhoff theorem hold also in void, we look at the schwarzschild metric:
$$\tag{1} ds^2~=~-\left(1-\frac{R}{r}\right)dt^2 
+ \left(1-\frac{R}{r}\right)^{-1}dr^2 +r^2 d\Omega^2$$
and take $M=0$ as there no mass inside the shell, we end up with the expected flat metric:
$$ds^2~=~-dt^2 + dr^2 +r^2 d\Omega^2$$

Comment: This answer is incorrect. See: https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.4428