Existence of hollow planets
Recently I read a sci-fi describing a species living in a closed hollow space in a planet. An earlier answer suggested that such structures could exist but will not be stable, if only effected by self gravity.
What would happen if I were to fall into a massive hollow planet?
Hence, I was wondering whether there could exist celestial bodies that:

are at least about the size of a planet (~$1000km$)
at stable equilibrium, admit a closed hollow space with dimension near the size of the whole object (diameter~$0.1 \times$ planet radius)

Can this be done by applying electric charge, spin, or placing other celestial bodies nearby?

By "hollow" do you mean of lower density than the crust? You might not require a literal vacuum, especially if a gas or liquid needs to sustain life as per the story. But while liquid cores may exist, low-density cores raise the question of why the crust hasn't fallen inward.

@J.G. Yes, I mean a significantly lower density area, and the question here is exactly whether there can be something preventing the crust falling.

Did you check this answer? https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/182727/269599

@user1079505 that is exactly the thing I mentioned in the OP. I hope to find something more stable than that.

Would you be satisfied with something like a 1000 sphere of charged aluminum foil? Not sure if that's feasible, but may help to clarify what do you mean. Anyway, isn't this question more suitable for worldbuilding SE?
