# Birkhoff and shell theorem - key differences

Tags: general-relativity, symmetry

Given a spherically symmetric mass distribution

- the [*shell theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) states that a test particle at radius $r$ experiences no net force from shells at a radius $R > r$;
- the [*Birkhoff theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_theorem_(relativity)) states that (with the additional condition of asymptotic flatness) the metric is static, and any vacuum shell corresponds to a radial branch of the Schwarzschild solution.

But the Birkhoff theorem does *not* explicitly say that geodesics of test particles at radius $r$ follow entirely from an „inner solution“ and are not affected by the mass distribution at $R > r$.

**Question**: Under which conditions is it possible to derive a similar statement like the shell theorem? Or do I overlook anything, and this „shell theorem“ is implicitly included in the Birkhoff theorem?

Comment: To be clear, are you asking whether the mass parameter in Sch. metric at given $r$ (where there is vacuum) would change if a shell of matter were introduced at some larger $r$?

Comment: In some sense yes. Given that any interior solution with density $\rho(r)$ and mass $m(r) = \int_0^r \rho$, plus vacuum $\rho(R) = 0$ for $R > r$ determines the metric and the geodesics at $r$ uniquely, the question is if the metric and the geodesics at $r$ can affected by adding densities $\rho(R) \neq 0$ for for $R > r$.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43626/2451

Comment: thanks; I am aware of that result, but it doesn’t answer my question